# Exporting Data to excel using SSIS and Data error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012, msbi

I have two different issues
   1).  I am trying to export data to excel from SQL Server database. The package will create a new excel file each day and insert the data from database to excel.

I want the column name to also be updated in the excel file. One way is to use a template and insert data into it. I don't want to use any kind of template as I want to create a new excel file daily. Is there any other method available ????

2).  I am trying to export data from server to excel. DATATYPE in server database is numeric. I am using a data conversion and changing to unicode string and then inserting it to excel.
       value in server database= 0.000
       value exported to excel=   .000
      help me fix it. I need 0.000 to be exported to excel

Answer (score 0):

1)  Yes, instead of a dataflow you can use a Script task to create the Excel file and write the data to it, and that will allow you to dynamically name the columns.

2)  It is not that SSIS is exporting that value to Excel.   That's just the way Excel is displaying the data.

Comment: Thanks for the help